# Create array of struct instances, then call function inside other struct passing array of objects (pointers)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I've already posted a question in relation to a problem similar to what I can expect on my college exam and now this is another concrete issue I'm facing, probably due to lacking crucial understanding of pointers.

The problem has several `struct`s defined.

One of them is `struct Question{}`, which has pointer attributes, and also an array which is to hold all the answers given for that particular question. At the destination, I should be able to iterate over all the questions in order to display them one by one to the user.

When I'm instantiating the exam (this is a simulation of an admission exam), I need to pass the student's citizen ID number, and the exam Questions.

```
// pi._prijavljeniKandidati[1]->_JMBG is the ID number in question
// 'questions' is supposed to carry all the questions I've hard-coded
// to save myself from entering manually

pi.StartExam(pi._prijavljeniKandidati[1]->_JMBG, questions);
```

This is how I tried it:

```
Question* questions = new Question;

// this initializes a single question
// 'answers' is the attribute that is holding all the answers
// the correct answer is BTW determined by an integer that is also
// sent in the below function

char* answers1[4];
answers1[0] = "London";
answers1[1] = "Berlin";
answers1[2] = "Helsinki";
answers1[3] = "Rome";

questions[0].Create("What is the capital of Finland?", answers1, 2);

// another question
char* answers2[3];
answers2[0] = "Ljubljana";
answers2[1] = "Paris";
answers2[2] = "Prague";

questions[0].Create("What is the capital of France?", answers2, 1);
```

And this is how the `StartExam` function actually looks like, nothing special here though, except that it shows how I tried getting some values of certain questions (based on the index thereof):

```
// I also tried void PokreniIspit(char* ID, Question* questions[])
void StartExam(char* ID, Question* questions)
{
    // this is just some dummy code line, to make sure it works
    cout << questions[1]._txtOfQuestion << endl;
}
```

When I run the app, the console crashes. Is there anything obvious that would make it crash?

For the sake of completeness, here's the whole Question structure:

```
// THIS IS HOW I IMAGING THIS STRUCT 'VISUALLY'
//= _txtOfQuestion ["Koji je glavni grad Njemacke?"]
//= _answers[10] //max 10 answers
//==== [0] Peking
//==== [1] London
//==== [2] Berlin
//==== [3] Seattle
//==== [4] Ljubljana
//= _posOfCorrect [2]
//= _points [4]

struct Question{

    char* _txtOfQuestion;
    char* _answers[4];
    int _posOfCorrect;
    int _points;

    void Unos(char* txt, char* answers[], int posCorrect, int points)
    {
        _txtOfQuestion= new char[strlen(txt) + 1];
        strcpy_s(_txtOfQuestion, strlen(txt) + 1, txt);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            _answers[i] = new char;
            strcpy_s(_answers[i], strlen(_answers[i]) + 1, _answers[i]);
        }

        _posOfCorrect = posCorrect;
        _points = points;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Create` method? How did it know the number of answers?

Comment: Done something similar. `Question* questions` and `questions[]` are considered equivalent, but, in my experience, `Question* questions` is supported in old version compilers, while `questions[]` does not.

Comment: @mch Find the entire struct in the bottom
I noticed something - I have this for loop and hardcoded `4` in it, while I'm actually sending variable no. of answers per a question. Might that be it?

Comment: `Question* questions = new Question;` is *one* question, not an array.

Comment: @crashmstr If you take a look at the reply a user wrote, I commented that I tried with the array, like this `= new Question[2]` for example. It didn't work. But stay tuned because I'm just about writing my own answer because posting this question opened my eyes - I noticed the culprit.

Comment: @developer10 I've re-read the entire question and the comments, but I'm still not seeing anywhere that you actually show or say you did `new Question[2];`. (except for your new answer, which does not count)

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, you're right. At this moment that comment is nowhere to be found - either I didn't submit it or a mod removed it. It was posted on the below answer beginning with: `Maybe you should try this instead:...`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying to help. Posting this question and going through all this code in order to translate from Bosnian to English helped me notice what was wrong.

Also, since I *did* initially try initializing `Question` like this:

```
Question* questions = new Question[2];
```

I'm back to using that because I do need array of questions.

But the real culprit (and cause for console to break) was the fact I had this `for` loop with the `4` hardcoded in it.

As soon as I made my second question contain 4 options/answers, just like the first one - it worked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    _odgovori[i] = new char;
    strcpy_s(_odgovori[i], strlen(odgovori[i]) + 1, odgovori[i]);
}
```

Comment: And this could be solved *easily* by using standard containers (such as `std::vector`).

Comment: @crashmstr That may be the case, but we are working with what we learned so far. However, yes, we are free to use whatever more advanced stuff and techniques we may know, but I'm not that advanced in C++. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Please be careful when using `strcpy_s`: The second parameter should hold the size of the destination string buffer, not of the source string buffer.

Comment: Also, consider using `std::string` as well. Modern C++ generally has much less need for `new`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Unos(const char* txt, const char* answers[], int posCorrect, int points)
{
    if (points < 4)
        points = 4; //max 4 answer possibilities

    _txtOfQuestion= new char[strlen(txt) + 1];
    strcpy_s(_txtOfQuestion, strlen(txt) + 1, txt);

    for(int i = 0; i < points; i++){
        _answers[i] = new char[strlen(answers[i]) + 1];
        strcpy_s(_answers[i], strlen(answers[i]) + 1, answers[i]);
    }
    _posOfCorrect = posCorrect;
    _points = points;
}
```

I changed a little bit:

Since you call the function with string literals, the type of this parameters should be `const char*`.

You should limit the `points` parameter (What happens if someone call it with 5 answers?).

The `for` loop should run from `0` to `points`. It would be undefined behaviour if it runs till 4 and there are only 3 answers.

You need an array of `char`s, not only 1 `char` to save the answer.

There were some typos in the `for` loop (`answers` is not the same as `_answers`).

I suggest to use `std::string` instead of `char*` and a `std::vector` or similar instead of the array.

You should call the function like:

```
questions[0].Create("What is the capital of Finland?", answers1, 2, 3);
```

there are only 3 answers, so you pass a `3` as last parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I myself caused some confusion in regards to the actual function call, as it actually needs to send the position of the correct answer within the answers array, AND the points earned if answered correctly. So, `points` (last argument) actually refers to that. Currently there's no argument implemented for the size of the questions array. I'm thinking about using some function to get the size of that array before the `for` loop.